# Spark RDD union OOM error when using single machine

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have the following code, that gets the distinct phone numbers, and create union of all the calls made.

```
//Get all the calls for the last 24 hours for each MSISDN in the hour
val sCallsPlaced = (grouped24HourCallsPlaS).join(distinctMSISDNs)
val oCallsPlaced = (grouped24HourCallsPlaO).join(distinctMSISDNs)
val sCallsReceived = grouped24HourCallsRecS.join(distinctMSISDNs)
val oCallsReceived = grouped24HourCallsRecO.join(distinctMSISDNs)

val callsToProcess = sCallsPlaced.union(oCallsPlaced)
                                 .union(sCallsReceived)
                                 .union(oCallsReceived)
```

The spark-defaults.conf file has the following:

```
spark.driver.memory=16g
spark.driver.cores=1
spark.driver.maxResultSize=2g

spark.executor.memory=24g
spark.executor.cores=10

spark.default.parallelism=256
```

The question is, will Spark be able to process 50G of data, with a 256G machine, with Hadoop services (namenode, datanode, secondaryname node), yarn, and HBase running on the same machine.

Hbase (HMaster, HQuorumPeer, and HRegionServers) take up around 20G each.

Also, is there a faster way than using "Union" in Spark.

Answer (score 0):

How many partitions are there for each RDD?  How does the Serde look for the records?

As for the relational algebra, maybe perform the unions first and then perform the join.